# Use enum type in function definition

Tags: scala, enums

I am struggling using a enum type in the function definition of Scala code.

What I did is:

```
object LogType extends Enumeration {
    type LogType = Value
    val TRACE = Value(100)
    val DEBUG = Value(90)
    val INFO = Value(80)
    val WARN = Value(70)
    val ERROR = Value(60)
    val FATAL = Value(50)
}

def logMessage(mtype: LogType, message: String): Unit = {

<console>:186: error: not found: type LogType
       def logMessage(mtype: LogType, message: String): Unit = {tring): Unit = {
```

It seems that the type is not found, although declared before the function definition.

Then the next question is how to use it within the function, in particular the syntax of this here (when to use value, etc.) is very confusing: scala def

```
logPerf(message: String, startTimeMillisec : Long, endTimeMillisec : Long): Unit = 
{    
val formatedmessage = String.format(message, (endTimeMillisec- startTimeMillisec) / 1000 + " ms")   
logMessage(LogType.TRACE, formatedmessage) 

}   

def logMessage(mtype: LogType.Value, message: String): Unit = {  

mtype match 
{     
case LogType.TRACE  => if( AssignedLogLevel <= mtype ){ log.trace( message ) 
}
```

https://i.postimg.cc/MHg6hNnv/log.png[log](https://i.postimg.cc/MHg6hNnv/log.png)[Log](https://i.postimg.cc/MHg6hNnv/log.png)

What would be correct in that case?

Comment: The correct type is `LogType.Value` - However, almost nobody uses `Enumeration` it is absolutely broken and unpleasant to use. Consider using either: `enum` _(only in **Scala 3**)_ a `sealed trait` + `case objects`, the **Enumeratum** library.

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Now I got this to at least compile, before I rebuild th whole thing (BTW, a sample would be great) how can I get the following lines to work with the initial approrach?

``
def logMessage(mtype: LogType.Value, message: String): Unit = {
mtype match {
    case LogType  => if( AssignedLogLevel <= mtype.Value ){ log.trace( message ) }
``

@Luis

Whereas the following preceeds the code above:

val AssignedLogLevel = LogType.TRACE

Comment: In particular the syntax of this here (when to use value, etc.) is very confusing:
  
```scala
def logPerf(message: String, startTimeMillisec : Long, endTimeMillisec : Long): Unit = {

  val formatedmessage = String.format(message, (endTimeMillisec- startTimeMillisec) / 1000 + " ms")
  logMessage(LogType.TRACE, formatedmessage)
}


def logMessage(mtype: LogType.Value, message: String): Unit = {

mtype match {
    case LogType.TRACE  => if( AssignedLogLevel <= mtype ){ log.trace( message ) }
```
[![log.png](https://i.postimg.cc/MHg6hNnv/log.png)]

Comment: Please edit the question or ask a different one, is hard to read comments and is not even clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of using a `trait`, as mentioned in the comments:

```
trait LogType {
  def level: Int
}

abstract class LogLevel(val level: Int) extends LogType

object TRACE extends LogLevel(100)
object DEBUG extends LogLevel(90)
object INFO extends LogLevel(80)
object WARN extends LogLevel(70)
object ERROR extends LogLevel(60)
object FATAL extends LogLevel(50)

def logMessage(mtype: LogType, message: String): Unit =
  if (mtype.level <= AssignedLogLevel) {
   log.trace(message)
  }
```

Comment: Great, thanks. THe implementation of the trait worked. Never worked with this before, I mainly have a C# background, thus trying to compare it with my homegrown language :-)´

What would be the last line of the image from above? (Line 22 in the picture)?

Comment: I've updated the answer with the code for `logMessage`

Comment: Would then the call to be ?


logMessage(LogType.TRACE, "SomeMessage")

Comment: Feel free to edit your code you have with a sample call :-)

Comment: Just `logMessage(TRACE, "SomeMessage")`